# Adapter with ViewHolder - loop

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-viewholder

I have a problem with my custom ListView adapter. I want to use ViewHolder (since my listview has 100+ elements), but my listview loops when I use my code. By looping I mean it shows only the initial position and loops their appearance until end of listview. I was suggesting from this site : [Click](http://optimizationtricks.blogspot.com/2014/01/tricks-to-boost-performance-of-list-view.html?m=1).

This is my code:

```
public class ListList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private final String[] web;
private final Integer[] imageId;
Context context;
public ListList(Context context,
String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
super(context, R.layout.champion_list, web);
this.context = context;
this.web = web;
this.imageId = imageId;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.champion_list, null);

        holder.txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        holder.img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img);
        holder.txt.setText(web[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }

    else {
        // View recycled !
        // no need to inflate
        // no need to findViews by id
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    return v;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt;
    ImageView img;
}
}
```

Any ideas where I did wrong? I tried putting .setText and .setImageResource out from if statement and it works, but according to this site I am doing wrong... Also can you give me any tips how to make listview "lag free"?

Comment: ViewHolder has nothing to do with View reusing and number of items in your adapter

Comment: By Showing Initial positions do you mean your list view shows duplicate content?

Comment: Good to know. Sorry, but i am learning about ViewHolder and  anything that optimizes listview. But doesn't ViewHolder optimize listview anyhow?

Comment: @KalpeshPatel - that is exactly what I had on my mind.

Comment: see @Blaze Tama answer he corrected your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
if(v == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.champion_list, null);

    holder.txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    holder.img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img);
    v.setTag(holder);
}

else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
}

//move here
holder.txt.setText(web[position]);
holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
```

Because you only set the text and image when the adapter loading a first item (the next items will re-use the holder)

Comment: I've done this before and I know it works, but does it mean guy on site which I linked is wrong?

Comment: @Darknez No, they are right. Take a look at their code, they also setVisibility outside the if-else (look my code).

Comment: Okay then. I was just wondering because my was still lagging same as before so i thought I've done something wrong. Anyway thanks for answer.

Comment: @Darknez ViewHolder is used to improve performance. since you are not doing `v.findViewById(R.id.txt);` every time you want to set text. `findViewById` is computationally expensive and view holder directly holds reference to your `textView` so you are saving `findViewById` call every time you want to assign new value. Same applies for any other view.

Comment: @Darknez try to make your holder class static, and please accept my answer :)